# Apps missing from Ubuntu Software

Tags: 18.04, software-center, brave

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, and when I went to install the browser Brave it told me "too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged".

Having no idea what this meant I purged snapd, and reinstalled it. Now Brave along with many other apps (like Sublime) don't appear on Ubuntu Software. Apps like Libre Office are all present.

What on earth is going on? Or rather, what did I do when I purged snapd?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling and reinstalling with the following command seems to have worked:

```
sudo apt autoremove gnome-software && sudo apt install gnome-software
```